# Python give datatype error when convert int64 to float

Tags: python, pandas

I download the data below and somehow, I won't be able to convert CENSUS2010POP (int64) into float. I am not sure what is wrong with the numbers.

Can you please help?
Thank you,
Hong
https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest/datasets/2010-2019/counties/totals/co-est2019-alldata.csv

```
pop = pd.read_csv(r'~\co-est2019-alldata.csv', sep=',' , encoding='latin-1')
pop.head(1)
print(pop.dtypes)

pop.CENSUS2010POP=float(pop.CENSUS2010POP)
```

Comment: `pop["CENSUS2010POP"] = pop["CENSUS2010POP"].astype(float)`

Comment: The error is "cannot convert ***pandas series*** to float", which makes sense.

Comment: Why are you converting a discrete, counting number to a float type anyway?

Comment: I try to do Benford analysis and somehow the code (working with other data) give error **TypeError: The sequence dtype was neither int nor float.
Convert it to whether int or float, and try again.**
I try everything I could to make work but fail. (It doesn't show the GREEN bar of actual value; just red line)
 
```pip install benford_py;
%matplotlib inline;import numpy as np;import pandas as pd;import benford as bf;

pop['CENSUS2010POP'] = pop['CENSUS2010POP'].astype(float)
f1d = bf.first_digits(pop.CENSUS2010POP, digs=1, decimals=8) ```